# reading file from getResourceAsStream omits newline

Tags: java

I'm reading a resource from getResourceAsStream, adding all text to a StringBuilder and writing the content to a new file. However, the text comes back without newlines.
When i do the same, but read a file without getResourceAsStream, it works perfectly.

The code looks like the following:

```
      InputStream styleFile = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "/path/path/path/some.css");

    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(styleFile));


    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int nextchar;
    while ((nextchar = bufRead.read()) != -1)
    {
       builder.append((char)nextchar);

    }
    FileWriter outFile;
    try
    {
       outFile = new FileWriter(newStyleFile);
    }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      //Log
   }

   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
   out.write(builder.toString());
   out.close();
```

Comment: You never use the `styleFile` variable which you get using `getResourceAsStream`. That's probably an error in the snippet you've posted.

Comment: Have you tried replacing reading character-by-character with line-by-line: `(nextLine = bufRead.readLine()) != null`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a BufferedReader.readLine() it reads everything upto the new line char. The new line character is not appended to the end of the chars you obtained. Its like tokenising on the new line character.. as for the BufferedReader.read() I am not too sure why the new line is getting skipped. The jdk source has something like this:

```
public int read() throws IOException {
synchronized (lock) {
    ensureOpen();
    for (;;) {
    if (nextChar >= nChars) {
        fill();
        if (nextChar >= nChars)
        return -1;
    }
    if (skipLF) {
        skipLF = false;
        if (cb[nextChar] == '\n') {
        nextChar++;
        continue;
        }
    }
    return cb[nextChar++];
    }
}
}
```

Anyway for your case.. Its simple to write a program that outputs the new line...

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(styleFile));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line=null;
while((line=br.readline())!=null){
    builder.append(line).append("\n");
}

// then write to the new file...
```